# How to access anaconda prompt in ubuntu terminal installed in windows 10?

Tags: windows, terminal, operating-system, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I have recently added the ubuntu terminal in my windows pc since certain packages were only supported in linux. Now for example if I were to access my packages that are present in my conda environments in my windows os through the linux terminal would it be possible? Will it still function the same way or do I have to manually install everything via the ubuntu terminal as well.
If I do have to install everything manually again, where will all the stored data be present? Which directories should I access?
How does this ubuntu terminal work exactly? Does it work in a similar manner if I were to dual boot it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access all the packages from Ubuntu terminal. You don't have to install everything all-together again. WSL or Ubuntu on Windows can seamlessly integrate with windows. Even though Linux systems have different directory structure, Ubuntu terminal (or bash or WSL or Ubuntu for Windows) happen to maintain the directory structure for windows. So anything you install on Ubuntu terminal will be installed as to windows terms. But I wouldn't recommend mixing these two as it's very tricky. And also, WSL and dual-booting Ubuntu with windows are far from close. You can know more about it if you search online.

I would personally recommend installing Ubuntu as it makes programming a billion times easier. You don't have to install Ubuntu replacing windows. You can just install Ubuntu on a separate hard drive and just specify which drive to boot from on system start-up. If you use a laptop and don't have two drives, then create a new volume and use it as if it were an original drive.